# Add custom class to Symfony form label

Tags: php, css, symfony, twig

I am building a Symfony 2.7 form and I would like to be able to customise the labels.

At the moment I am able to define the labels using the form builder outlined in the [Symfony docs](https://symfony.com/doc/2.7/forms.html), however I can't see any way to customise the CSS of the label without having to do it on the template.

I know that I would be able to add the CSS class by individually printing the `form_label` inside of a  with my class, but I would prefer to keep it all inside of the form builder.

I've added my current form below for reference.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('dob_day', 'choice', array(
            'required' => true,
            'choices' => $dobDays,
            'mapped' => false,
            'attr' => array(
                'label' => 'Day',
                'class' => 'form-control'
            )
        ))

        ->add('dob_month', 'choice', array(
            'required' => true,
            'choices' => $dobMonths,
            'mapped' => false,
            'attr' => array(
                'label' => 'Month',
                'class' => 'form-control'
            )
        ))

        ->add('dob_year', 'choice', array(
            'required' => true,
            'choices' => $dobYears,
            'mapped' => false,
            'attr' => array(
                'label' => 'Year',
                'class' => 'form-control'
            )
        ));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to add some CSS to your HTML in the form type, use the `style` attribute.

```
->add('dob_year', 'choice', array(
    'required' => true,
    'choices' => $dobYears,
    'mapped' => false,
    'attr' => array(
        'label' => 'Year',
        'class' => 'form-control',
        'style' => 'max-width: 4rem;'. // Concat. the styles across lines for clarity.
            'border: solid 0.1rem teal;'
    )
));
```

### That said,

inside the `formType` is probably the last place I'd go looking to modify these elements' styles if I was the poor dev who had to maintain this form when you were gone.

While it's possible to add inline CSS here, don't put more than a few lines. If it grows to be more, add a class to some external 'main.css' then add that to your primary template (that all others inherit from) and you'll be able to reuse the styles you've made.

### Last thought

This is actually pretty helpful when you're trying to make your `formType` modular and is why I wanted to answer :) Then I got carried away in a *best practice* mantra that came off as if this technique doesn't have its place, but it does!

Comment: Thanks for that @rhono, I really should think about the extendibility of this form by not using too many styles in the form builder :)